# Android Studio Not Connecting To Firebase

Tags: android-studio

I need Some Help. I want To Connect Firebase To My Android Studio, But Some Error Appears. Like: Could Not Parse The Nsdroid Application Module's Gradle Config. Resolve Gradle Build Issue and/or resync. Error Pictures: https://i.stack.imgur.com/OvjWQ.png

Answer (score 0, accepted):

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services' Remove This one and try to sync.